# Are the Euler substitutions valid only for rational functions?

Tags: integration

I am self-studying, Now I try to learn integrals, Especially the Euler's substitution.

1. if $a > 0$: we put $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} = \pm \sqrt{a}x+t$
2. if $c \ge 0$ :  $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} = xt \pm \sqrt{c}$

In books, I find that these substitutions are applicables for the following form:

$$  \int{R(x, \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}) \mathrm{d}x} $$

**My question is:** are these substitutions applicables only for rational functions? can I apply it for this form :
 $$ \int{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}\, \mathrm{d}x}$$ ?

Please do not forget that I am self-studying and I try to do all my efforts .

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the function $y$ is a rational function in $x$ and $y$, or rather $y \in \{R(x,y)\}$.
For you, this means that your last integral
$$ \int \sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c} dx $$
is *still a rational function* of the form $R(x, \sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c})$. And indeed, you can proceed with Euler substitution.

Comment: Please, I said I am not mathematician I cannot understand what you wrote (your notation) can you explain please?

Comment: What you wrote down **is** a rational function.