# What does it mean the notation $\int{R\left( \cos{x}, \sin{x} \right)\mathrm{d}x} $

Tags: integration

Sometimes I find this notation and I get confused:
 $$\int{R\left( \cos{x}, \sin{x} \right)\mathrm{d}x} $$

Does it mean **a rational function** or **taking rational operations** between $\cos{x}$ and $\sin{x}$ ?

Can you explain please?

**Update:** I think you did not understand the question well,
Here is an example (maybe it is a lemma or a theorem):

> All the integrals of the form $\int{R\left( \cos{x}, \sin{x}
>  \right)\mathrm{d}x} $ can be evaluated using the substitution
>   $u=\tan{\dfrac{x}{2}} $.

I think that $R$ here does not stand for a rational function but for taking rational operations(addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) between $\cos{x} $ and $\sin{x}$

**Update** : I did not noticed that $R$ is a rational function of **two variables** and that means exactly that we are taking rational operations.

Comment: The assumption is exactly that R is a rational function.

Comment: What is, in your opinion, the difference between "a rational function of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$" and "taking rational operations between $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$"?

Comment: The two things that you talk about (and mistakenly consider to be different) can be proven to be, in fact, identical.

Comment: No they are completly different

Comment: Please read the question before downvoting. the book says: **The symbol R** and **does not say rational function**

Comment: I agree that the downvoting is foolish (as are most of the voting patterns on this site, unfortunately); nonetheless, you should edit with an explanation of what book you're using.

Comment: OP: These matters were already explained to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685907/are-the-euler-substitutions-valid-only-for-rational-functions#comment3441132_1685919

Comment: @Did: I expect the answer to be : Yes or No. if it is Yes (explain why) if it not also explain why. this is why asked the question and what I am expecting. So please answer the question (if there is an ambiguity) explain it

Comment: OK, here is the answer: *$R$ denotes a rational function*.

Comment: @Did can you explain why?

Comment: See my comment making a distinction between the functions $R$ and $f$.

Comment: @Did: I am not a mathematician like you, I cannot understand the difference

Comment: You mean you cannot understand from my comments down there why $R$ and $f$ are not the same object? If $R=f$, one can do with $f$ everything one can do with $R$, right? And $R(2,3)=6$, right? So what is $f(2,3)$? The only rule you can use is the definition of $f$ as a function such that $f(x)=\cos x\sin x$ for every real number $x$, but $(2,3)$ is not a real number, hence you are stuck from the start. QED.

Comment: @Did: $R(2,3)$ means simply: $\dfrac{2}{3}$ or $\dfrac{3}{2}$. So why $R(2,3) = 6$?

Comment: @Navaro No, $R(x,y)$ can be any rational function, so it could be $xy$ or $x+y$ or $\frac{x}{y}$ or $\frac{x^2+xy+x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ or any number of things. It is not necessarily a ratio of one argument to the other. Perhaps that is why the term "rational operation" confused you.

Comment: @Lan this is what I talking about: and this is rational operations not a rational function

Comment: @Lan : $xy$ is a rational function??!!

Comment: My username here is Ian, not Lan. Anyway, what is the difference in your eyes? I've pointed out the only thing that I can think of that would confuse you already, which is that usually when we say "rational function" we mean "rational function of one variable", whereas you can have rational functions of several variables. And yes, $xy$, like all polynomials, is technically a rational function, since you can view it as $\frac{xy}{1}$.

Comment: Sorry Ian, Please do you notice that this is what I am looking for in the answer? Actually I cannot understand it well, can you answer the question please and explain the ambiguity between rational functions and what makes me confused? please

Comment: See page two of http://www.math.utah.edu/~wortman/1060text-pitv.pdf for the form of degree 0,1 and 2 polynomials of two variables; the extension to higher degrees should be clear (for cubics for example, you include an $x^3$ term, a $y^3$ term, an $x^2y$ term, and an $xy^2$ term). A rational function of two variables (which is what $R$ in your original question is, contrary to all your objections) is a ratio of two polynomials of two variables.

Comment: @lanI noticed that the question was misunderstood so i changed it (Sorry maybe because I am not native english)

Comment: The point that Did and Christian Blatter and I have been trying to make is that you have not made it entirely clear what "taking rational operations" means exactly. By contrast "rational function" is a clearly defined term, whose definition can be looked up. I can tell you from the context (because you are talking about the half-angle substitution) that your $R$ is a rational function. Maybe it can be described the other way too, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: @lan, taking rational operations between cosine and sine means that I can write: $\cos{x}+\sin{x}$, or $\cos{x}-\sin{x}$ or $\cos{x}/\sin{x}$ or $\cos{x}*\sin{x}$ ...etc.

Comment: BTW: why they downvote the question? what wrong with it?

Comment: But is it just one operation, or can you do many? And can you multiply by constants? Or add constants? The term "rational function" answers all these questions.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. $ $

Answer (score 6):

Here $R$ is a function of two variables $s$ and $t$. For instance, if $$R(s,t) = \frac{s}{1+t}$$ then $$R(\cos x , \sin x) = \frac{\cos x}{1 + \sin x}.$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39281/discussion-on-answer-by-umberto-p-what-does-it-mean-the-notation-intr-left).

Answer (score 1):

In books with tables of integrals etc. (like Gradshteyn's book) $R(\cos x, \cos y)$ typically means a rational function of $(\cos x, \sin x)$. So take a rational function $R(a,b)=f^{1}(a,b)/f^{2}(a,b)$ and  plug in $a=\cos x, b=\sin x$. Here, $f^{i}(a,b), i=1,2$ are polynomials in the two variables $(a,b)$, i.e.,
$$f^{i}(a,b)=c^i_{0,0}+c^i_{1,0}a+c^i_{0,1}b+c^i_{2,0}a^2+c^i_{0,2}b^2+c^i_{1,1}ab+\dots$$
with coefficients $c^{i}_{k,l}$.

Answer (score 1):

A *polynomial* in two variables is an expression
$$
P(x, y) = \sum_{i, j=0}^{\infty} a_{ij} x^{i} y^{j}
$$
with only *finitely many* non-zero coefficients $a_{ij}$. A *rational function* in two variables is a quotient of polynomials in two variables.

In your question, $R$ denotes an arbitrary rational function of two variables. (It's arguably reasonable to describe "evaluating a rational function of two variables $x$ and $y$" as "taking rational operations between $x$ and $y$", but the number of comments here and elsewhere suggests doing so is a recipe for ambiguity.)

We can be certain of this interpretation on grounds of mathematical culture: Thanks to the double-angle formulas for the circular functions and the chain rule, the substitution $u = \tan(x/2)$, or $x = 2\arctan u$, gives
$$
\cos x = \frac{1 - u^{2}}{1 + u^{2}},\qquad
\sin x = \frac{2u}{1 + u^{2}},\qquad
dx =  \frac{2\, du}{1 + u^{2}}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\int R(\cos x, \sin x)\, dx
  = \int R\left(\frac{1 - u^{2}}{1 + u^{2}}, \frac{2u}{1 + u^{2}}\right) \frac{2\, du}{1 + u^{2}},
$$
a *rational function* in $u$.

The significance is, every rational function in one variable has an elementary primitive (antiderivative).

Comment: This is exactly what I expected the answer to be like